# Can I set the width of a column in percents in GridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

I have an alert dialog that contains a `RecyclerView`. Each item in the recycler is a simple checkbox. I need to draw it in three columns.

For this I use GridLayoutManager

```
layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

What I see is in a result is this

[image]

Not bad. The problem is that I need to set every column's width to 33% of the width of my dialog. I don't have any fixed width of my checkbox in pixels as text can vary. Here's a layout used for the recycler.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable name="item" type="..." />
    </data>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="@={item.enabled}"
        android:text="@{item.name}"
        android:minWidth="40dp"/>

</layout>
```

My Recycler is created with the width equals to parent

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Any ideas how to set width in percents?

Comment: have you tried changing checkbox size to match parent?

Comment: yes, it draws only a first column in this case

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your `RecyclerView` is laid out correctly, You can force `ViewHolder` size by overriding layout params within `LayoutManager`:

```
layoutManager = object : GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false){
    override fun checkLayoutParams(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams) : Boolean {
        // force width of viewHolder to be a fraction of RecyclerViews
        // this will override layout_width from xml
        lp.width = width / spanCount
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I'd set 5 columns on a large screen (or when rotating the screen)?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I slightly altered answer, You can use `spanCount` (column count) instead of hard coding "3". Now it's up to You how to modify column count passed to `GridLayoutManager`, for example create custom `columnCount` integer resource that will have different values depending on user configuration and obtain it with `context.resources.getInteger(R.integer.columnCount)`.

Comment: where does it come from? there also would be a getter `getSpanCount()`. not hard-coding it is in every case better, because dynamic column-count is quite common.

Comment: `getSpanCount()` is java method of `GridLayoutManager`, and it's available as `spanCount` in Kotlin due to interop properties conversion.

Comment: have forgotten about that difference. that's always easier in the IDE.

Comment: Say, how does the IDE know what is "width" ? It reached the RecyclerView even though I don't see any clue for this on code...

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` you've told the recycler view to fill left-to-right, rather than top-to-bottom.  By saying you want a `spanCount` of 3, what you've actually asked is for each *column* to have up to 3 items in it.  That's why your items go from 1 to 3 in the first column before spilling over to the second column, rather than going from 1 to 3 in the first row.

While there are plenty of cases where this is desirable, from your question's wording I suspect you want a fixed number of columns (3) and each column to have 33% of the width.  You can achieve this by using a `GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL` orientation and setting each child's size to `MATCH_PARENT` which should have the effect you're after.